# How do i stop my server in java

Tags: java, serversocket

How do i stop a server cause the `ss.close()` doesn't stop the server.
I am using the following code :

```
    public class Server {
        ServerSocket ss;
        boolean listening;


        public void StartServer() {
            try {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);
                listening = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server started");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ioe);
            }


        while(listening) {
            try {
                new Session(ss.accept());
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ioe);
            }
        }
    }

    public void StopServer() {
        try {
            ss.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
  }
```

I call the StopServer method somewhere else.
I have also tried to set listening to false.
Where i call the StartServer method i placed a Message Dialog to see if it continues.

```
    private void btn_StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
            lbl_Image2.setText("");
            lbl_Image2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("../../Project/Images/GreenButton.png"));
            lbl_Image2.setVisible(true);
            btn_Start.setEnabled(false);
            btn_Stop.setEnabled(true);
            SV.StartServer();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stopped");
    }
```

When I try to call the `StopServer()` the message dialog doesn't pop up.

Comment: Inside StartServer() you shouldn't be doing this: ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777); because you defined ServerSocket as a field already. So it should be ss = new ServerSocket(7777).

Comment: Doesn't this code throw NPE on each run?

Comment: @Xabster No it doesn't throw a NPE. Thanks just had to change the ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777); to ss = new ServerSocket(7777);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);` to `ss = new ServerSocket(7777);`. The `ss` variable referenced in the `StopServer()` method is not the same one that is started in `StartServer()`.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to give control of starting/stopping the server, you have to create GUI based server  in threads. Because in StartServer method following while loop will not release its control called by the component (Start Button).

```
while(listening) {
        try {
            new Session(ss.accept());
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ioe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just noticed that. Thanks @Sarz